# How do you use a variable as an index when slicing integers in Python?

Tags: python

so im learning programming (python, visual studio community) and im trying to write a game in python and the best way of describing it is mastermind (a chosen length of numbers are randomly generated, you guess and it tells you if there are correct numbers in the correct position but not which position they are in) it seems as if everything else in this works so far apart from the fact that because this program will be able to do an infinite length i must check these numbers using a variable that increases by 1 each time `if guess[y]==randomnumber[y]:`, every time i run this i get the error msg:"'int' object is not subscriptable".
here is the full code:

```
length=int(input("what length do you want: "))
import random
if length==0:
    length=int(input("what length do you want: "))
if length!=0:
    x=0
    while x!=length:
        randomnumber=[int(random.randint(0,9))]
        x=x+1
    x=0
    game_over=0
    while game_over==0:
        guess=int(input("your guess:    "))
        y=0
        round_score=0
        y=int(y)
        while y!=length:
            if guess[y]==randomnumber[y]:
                round_score=round_score+1
            y=y+1
        if round_score==length:
            game_over=1
```

Comment: `guess` is an `int`, not a `list`.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with the `[y]` in `guess[y]`? Also, what are you hoping to do with `y=int(y)` when `y` is already an integer? In general, you should be able to attach a purpose to everything you type in a program, but in this case you seem to be typing code that doesn't have any obvious purpose.

Comment: What is going on here: ```randomnumber=[int(random.randint(0,9))]```? You essentially produce a list with one random number for a couple of times (```length```). You probably want to collect them in a ```list``` of length ```length```.

Comment: The title of your question asks about how to slice integers, but "slicing integers" doesn't really make sense. Integers are not the sort of thing that one slices in Python. It might help if you explained what you meant by slicing integers.

Comment: Maybe off topic but I think you meant `while length==0:` instead of `if length==0`, in line 3 because you want to keep asking if length is 0 and not just once

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert the guess to a list of ints.

Get input as string:

```
guess = input("your guess: ")
```

Sequence of characters (aka string) to int list:

```
guess = [int(c) for c in guess]
```

This could be written in one line but I think it is more clear this way.